# How to change color of svg images in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, svg

I want to change color of svg images. I am using following code, it hides the image and fill the whole image view with the color set.

```
 self.badmintonImgView.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

I need to change the color of image. Please suggest

Comment: try this ...   .theImageView.image = [theImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[theImageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: @SudheerKolasani: Tried that, same result.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage

Comment: @SudheerKolasani: no luck. Tried those categories.

Comment: Does SVGKit not give you access to the SVG's current color? My own SVGgh allows you to selectively colorize elements marked with currentColor.

Comment: you can see this method I answered:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/42591944/5686513](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42591944/5686513) It works I have tested.

Answer (score 60):

If the `SVG` is in `Assets.xcassets`, you can tell Xcode to treat the image as an icon:

First, select your `SVG` image in the assets catalog

Then set the render mode to **Template Image**

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Swift

To change the color of an SVG using Swift:

```
badmintonImgView.image = badmintonImgView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
badmintonImgView.tintColor = UIColor.orange
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### This worked for me:

```
UIImage * imageOrange = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourSVGImageName"] imageWithTintColor:UIColor.orangeColor];
UIImageView * yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imageOrange];
```

remember add the image to the `assets` folder.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me though its supported after iOS 13.

Answer (score 2):

For publishing iOS 14.0+, I used אורי orihpt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66672337/12155602), but realized I had to do some additional steps that differ from other answers on here. When using the `Image`, I couldn't get `tintColor` to work, but `foregroundColor` worked for me. I don't know if you're targeting the whole image, but this solution targets only the SVG paths, instead of creating a background color as well on the image (similar to Marcy's [output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647557/12155602) image).

```swift
Image("imageName")
  .foregroundColor(Color.red)
```

Comment: Now .foregroundColor is deprecated and the new API is .foregroundStyle(.red)

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow may be work for you.

```
SVGKImage *svgImage = [SVGKImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGENAME"];
SVGKLayeredImageView *svgImageView = [[SVGKLayeredImageView alloc] initWithSVGKImage:svgImage];
[capturedImageView addSubview:svgImageView];

CALayer* layer = svgImageView.layer;
for (CALayer *subLayer in layer.sublayers) {

    for (CALayer *subSubLayer in subLayer.sublayers) {


        for (CALayer *subSubSubLayer in subSubLayer.sublayers) {

            if( [subSubSubLayer isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]){
                CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer*)subSubSubLayer;
                shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor BlackColor].CGColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting errors while using SVGKit, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SVGKit. Can you help here?

Comment: In the SVGKit-iOS target > Build Settings locate the "Other C Flags" and "Other C++ Flags" sections and add the following: -fembed-bitcode

Comment: Try above solution

Comment: Same errors upon adding In the SVGKit-iOS target > Build Settings locate the "Other C Flags" and "Other C++ Flags" sections and add the following: -fembed-bitcode

Comment: I think you have use library using pod..?

Comment: Please remove static library first then insatall using cocoa pods

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5.X Solution primary for SVG images loaded dynamically from web:**

Note: Although this solution works also for images loaded from `Assets` folder and images of other than `.svg` types.

```
extension UIImage {
/// - Description: returns tinted image
/// - Parameters:
///   - qualityMultiplier: when treating SVG image we need to enlarge the image size in order to preserve quality. The smaller the original SVG is compared to desired UIImage frame, the bigger multiplier should be.
/// - Returns: Tinted image
func withTintColor(_ color: UIColor, qualityMultiplier: CGFloat = 15) -> UIImage? {
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: size.width * qualityMultiplier, height: size.height * qualityMultiplier), false, scale)
    // 1 We create a rectangle equal to the size of the image
    let drawRect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: size.width * qualityMultiplier,height: size.height * qualityMultiplier)
    // 2 We set a color and fill the whole space with that color
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(drawRect)
    // 3 We draw an image over the space with a blend mode of .destinationIn, which is a mode that treats the image as an image mask
    draw(in: drawRect, blendMode: .destinationIn, alpha: 1)

    let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return tintedImage
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try this
[self.badmintonImgView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: This is the same basic code shown in the question.